# If AND statements in google script to move data to another sheet based on change in one cell and value in another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

OK, I'm fairly new at doing this.  I have a google spreadsheet that I populate and then run a script to create forms are created to complete tasks.  My end users mark the task as completed.  I am wanting entries in the spreadsheet that change to yes AND are Validate tasks to copy to another sheet (Log).  I can get the entries to copy if I just have a watcher for yes but am having problems putting the other if statement for the task in there.  Here is what I have for a test...

```
function onChange() {
  // moves a row from any sheet to an archive sheet when a magic value is entered in a column
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column D */ 4; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "yes";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "LOG";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if ( sheet.getName() != sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo && cell.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch
      && cell.getValue().toLowerCase() == valueToWatch) {
    if (cell.getColumn() == 2 && cell.getValue() == "Validate") {  
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1,  sheet.getLastColumn())
        .copyTo(targetRange);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to watch two separate locations with the same `cell` variable.  You start by initializing `cell` as the active cell, then check that the column is #4, then in the second `if` statement you use `cell` to `getColumn` 2.

Maybe create a new set of variables to use for the validation check:

```
var activeRow=cell.getRow();
var valCheck=sheet.getRange(activeRow, 2);
```

then the `if` statement changes to:

```
if (valCheck.getValue() == "Validate") {
```

Comment: Thanks Ron.  It worked adding the new variable and then I added an or statement.function...var activeRow = cell.getRow();
var taskCheck=sheet.getRange(activeRow, 2);

if (sheet.getName() != sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo && cell.getColumn() ==columnNumberToWatch && cell.getValue().toLowerCase() == valueToWatch && 
  (taskCheck.getValue() == "Verfication Report"||taskCheck.getValue() == "Maintenance Memo"||taskCheck.getValue() == "Check Report")){

Comment: Awesome.  It might be good to put that together into an answer for anyone else coming back to this later.  It's hard to read in a comment.